# Are there villains that wear a helmet in Star Trek?

Tags: star-trek

Probably the most well known character in science fiction that wears a helmet would be Darth Vader (Correct me if I'm wrong. I haven't seen any Star Wars movie, but Vader is the one that had me thinking about this question).

The only villain I can think of would be the Hirogen.

[image]

Comment: Breen?  https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Breen

Comment: @jo1storm - I never realized that! I always assumed they were some advanced androids.

Comment: aren't the new and improved Pakled's in Lower Decks sometimes seen sporting helmets? TOS era Romulans were seen in helmets. Of course many Borg have some kind of plasticy-outer-covering on their pasty grey skulls. Not sure what you'd define as a villain, but Hunters from the Gamma quadrant wore helmets. - https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Helmet

Comment: Helmet or mask? There's a big different between the two. Title says one thing, body says another.

Comment: @Valorum - Helmet, but I like your answer.

Comment: @NKCampbell - The ones that were hunting Tosk, right?

Comment: There was the knight in TOS "Shore Leave", but that's stretching things...

Comment: Vader was a villain. :)

Answer (score 14):

[Memory-Alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Helmet) has a surprising few examples of helmets listed, but there are a couple of well known antagonists that wore them.

- First is the Romulan commander [Decius](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Decius) from TOS *Balance of Terror*.
  [image: Decius]
- Second is the [Breen](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Breen) from Deep Space Nine.
  [image: Breen]

Comment: The Breen remind of the Cylons. I wonder if one took inspiration from the other?

Comment: @EmpressSvetlana  Battlestar Galactica (2004-2009)is with its Cylons is a reboot of Battlestar Galactics (1978-79) and Galactica 1980 with their Cylons.  The Breenw ere seen in DS9 in the 1990s.

Comment: So it's Cylons -> Breen. If anything, DS9 took inspiration from BSG (I'm not officially claiming they did. Just a thought).

Comment: I always thought the Breen helmets had a lot of similarities with Leia's bounty hunter disguise from Return of the Jedi. There are unverified rumors on the web to that effect but nothing concrete.

Comment: @EmpressSvetlana :D I love it! The Breen always reminded me of Princess Leia when she was undercover during the [thermal detonator scene](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R0yOCHd7Mjs) in Jabba's lair.

Comment: @EmpressSvetlana Ronald D. Moore, creator of the BSG reboot, was also a writer for DS9,  so he may have had something to do with it.

Answer (score 6):

For me, the best "mask-wearing villain" in Trek history is [Sulan](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Sulan). He literally ripped the face off of a redshirt and wore it because he thought it made him look pretty.

[image]

Comment: And even worse, a red-shirt played by a recognisable actor who had appeared in two or three episodes [EDIT: actually, only one episode] prior, so we had started to identify and like the character. One of the best and most devious things they did in the whole 7 seasons of Voyager.

Comment: Is their any reason why we haven't seen any more iconic villains in Star Trek wear helmets? Is it to avoid comparisons to Star Wars?

Comment: Question is about helmets.

Comment: @lucasbachmann - Yes, that's certainly what it's about after OP edited out the references to masks.

Answer (score 5):

Might as well throw in the ["Hunters",](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Hunter) from DS9's "Captive Pursuit".

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Do the foot-soldiers for the Albino (the villain of the DS9 episode *Blood Oath*) count? They wore helmets with one-way visors that covered their faces.

Comment: Are they villains though? At best they're hired goons

Comment: @Valorum- they're not much different from Imperial Stormtroopers- wouldn't you consider *them* villains?